# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 35447-35448: character maps to <undefined> in SUBLIME

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, printing, utf-8, sublimetext

If I run python script in windows command line it prints non-English letters fine but when I run it in Sublime it produces this error:

```
  print("feed is: " + str(feeds))
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\Envs\proj_env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 35447-35448: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have included this in the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And I saved the file as UTF-8 from the file --> save with encoding